# locating an element from parent to child

Tags: jquery

I have several columns (ul) contain lists (li). When I click on one of the elements I want to locate the element first on the list which has a class 'all'

```
<div id=1>
    <ul>
        <li class="list all">ALL</li>
        <li class="list">1</li>
        <li class="list">2</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li class="list">3</li>
        <li class="list">4</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li class="list">5</li>
        <li class="list">6</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id=2>
    <ul>
        <li class="list all">ALL</li>
        <li class="list">1</li>
        <li class="list">2</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li class="list">3</li>
        <li class="list">4</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li class="list">5</li>
        <li class="list">6</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

On click of any class="list", I want to addClass "selected" to the element with class="all", but only for the one in the same containing div.
I just don't seem to be able to use the right selector to find it

```
parent = $(this).parent().parent().children().$('.all').addClass('selected');
```

But it doesn't work, and I am not sure how it would select the first ul in the containing div.

Comment: Can you make it more clear. Any Demo url or fiddle is there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$(".list").click(function(){

$(this).closest("div").find(".all").first().addClass("selected")

})
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/T3MaV/)

Getting clicked **li** parent **div** and then finding first element with class **all** and adding class selected.

**Revised Code:**

```
$(".list").click(function(){

    $(".all.selected").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).closest("div").find(".all").first().addClass("selected")

    })
```

[**REVISED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/T3MaV/1/)

Comment: To remove the classes, it would again be the classes in the containing div, not the other divs. How would I do that?

Comment: ``$(this).closest("div").find(".all.selected").removeClass("selected");``

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find the `div` parent of the clicked `list` and then use .find()`to find the`.all` element

```
parent = $(this).closest('div').find('.all').addClass('selected');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/69ptn/)

Answer (score 0):

Try,
  use `closest` to to find immediate parent of type div then search for the descendant with class `all` and add class for it as you wish

```
$(".all" , $(this).closest('div')).addClass('selected');
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `.closest()` to find parent div and use `.find()` to find `.all` li

```
parent = $(this).closest('div').find('.all:first').addClass('selected');
```

Comment: I'm downvoting you because there are already four appropriate answers from up to 3 minutes ago, you must have seen them.

Comment: @scrowler, yeah I got little late to post my answer coz internet problem.